# Facebook Graph API returning weird HTML instead of JSON

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Since yesterday we had an increase in errors related to our integration to get users' data with the Facebook API.

We're using **Facebook's official SDK v5.5.0**, and **Graph API v2.9**:

```
...

$accessToken = $user->getAccessToken();

$response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id, name, email, friends', $accessToken);

$profile = $response->getDecodedBody();

...
```

This integration worked fine, the `$profile` variable would be an array with `id` and `name`, at least. However, since yesterday, I've noticed this weird response:

[image: Facebook SDK Weird Response]
So far, only a few users have been affected by this issue but I'm afraid this could be a bug on Facebook's side or is it related to the SDK configuration? Does anyone know how to proceed and prevent this issue?

**Note:** Already checked the access tokens, they are all valid and, if they weren't, Facebook SDK would have thrown an Exception there.

Thanks

Comment: `fields=id, name, email, friends` - spaces are for sure not allowed there

Comment: @MateuszSip Thanks, but I just formatted this for better visibility here, the query string is trimmed by the SDK anyway.

Comment: Can you show what getBody returns as well? And maybe what getHttpStatusCode and getHeaders return, too.